# JasperException: absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: jsp, jstl

I've been having the following problem with my GoDaddy's server.
I am using JSPs with the JSTL Library. My /WEB-INF/lib folder contains the following libraries:

jstl.jar
standard.jar

My JSP looks something like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<p>Hello!   <%
out.print(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); 

%></p>
```

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri:
     http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml
     or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Any ideas as to why it is doing that?

Comment: what version of JSTL are you using?

Comment: As you explicitly mentioned Godaddy, may I assume that it "just" works at local dev environment? If so, how does your `web.xml` look like?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to get the right version of JSTL, they use different URIs.

If that one's not working, try: http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar (JSTL 1.2), or pull down the 1.1 JSTL jars.

There's a more detailed list of versions/URIs at [coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/660048/Wiki/Jstl-Tag-Lib-Definitions).

Comment: or if you are using maven:         <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: The javaranch link is dead... would've been more useful to include this information here rather than linking to a third party site.

Answer (score 4):

you need to add Following jar file in your web application

```
jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar
and jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar files
```

Recently I have same problem, that i have resolved by adding above two jar files

Answer (score 3):

I used Tomcat6 37.
As for me, I tried mentioned above solutions but still got the error.
The problem solved after adding the jstl-1.2.jar to my %CATALINA_HOME%\lib directory.

Comment: That happens because the jstl-1.2.jar is somehow not available, adding it to the server libs is not a good idea, while it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here were useful to explain the problem but it did not help me diagnose *why* it was happening when I thought I was loading the right JSTL versions.  Ultimately I had to debug the application and put a breakpoint in the TLD file processor (maybe `org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.getTagLibraryInfos()`) to see from where it was getting the TLD files.

I then discovered that it was loading old versions of the TLD files from a jar that I did not suspect had them -- it was a dependency of the GWT (ick) subsystem.  Once the offending jar was removed from my maven dependencies, the problem was resolved.

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I'm facing an eerily similar problem (also with JSTL in GWT - I'm assuming the Jetty server used by GWT's super dev mode has something to do with it). Do you happen to remember _which_ offending jar you had to remove to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry but I can't remember.  I think I used debug mode and looked to see which jar I was in once it stopped.  Best of luck.

Comment: No worries, thanks - I'll take a poke around and see if I can find which jar it is. Can't believe it's this difficult to use GWT with JSTL...