# Absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application error in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I just deleted the tomcat server and added it back in Eclipse Kepler and then I am getting this error when I run my project.Before deleting the server there was no issues.

Part of my POM contains :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and My JSP page contains :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

I tried other solutions from Here but did not resolve my issue.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: JSTL is not part of Servlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one from [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Read similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427486/jasperexception-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resol)

Comment: I added jstl jar into my tomcat/lib folder and it worked.But I do not know why?Any idea?

Comment: Find the reason in the link that I shared you in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this worked, adding the jar to Tomcat didn't.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```