# The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, jstl

I searched several other threads on this error, most of them either had the wrong/missing maven dependency or had the wrong uri in their taglib.

As far as I know, I've got everything correct and my app keeps failing once I get to the jsp where I use JSTL.

This is the taglib I'm using:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And these are my maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As far as I know, from the servlet api 2.4 on you need jstl 1.2, which I have, so I really don't see the problem here...

EDIT: I see this question has been marked as a duplicate, though it isn't. The referring question was solved by fixing the uri of the `taglib`, here it was a case of adding jstl to tomcat's lib folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `jstl-1.2.jar` to my `tomcat/lib` folder. As tomcat doesn't have the jstl jar and by putting my scope on `provided` I had to make sure my container (tomcat) had the relevant jar available.

Though I haven't tested it, this should also work by leaving the `jstl` jar on the default compile scope

Answer (score 1):

Try this one from [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Read similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427486/jasperexception-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resol)

---

Update the version

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Find similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391687/absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either-web/24392190#24392190) as well. That works.

Comment: It has the exact same answer you gave me

Comment: read the question as well of the shared links. try with updated version of the javax.servlet-api

Comment: clean the project and click to maven update project. Look in the repository that jar is present or not with the corrected version. Check whether dependencies is resolved or not.

Comment: Tried it, the jar is there with the right version, dependencies are resolved, still fails :(

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`javax.servlet` moved to above.

Comment: Have you tried by changing servlet from 2.5 to 3 ? try it, if not solve then post me.