# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error while deploy war file in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I used *apache-tomcat-8.5.50* and tried to follow this tutorrial from https://o7planning.org/en/11583/installing-and-configuring-tomcat-server . 
[image]

After deploy war file to tomcat server I got this error like this

[image]

I do not know what happen is. Could you help me to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Visit below link.

[JasperException: absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427486/jasperexception-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resol/19245606#19245606)

The error is an environmental issue on your PC. I think tomcat can't find jstl.jar.

Comment: Thank you .I added jstl.jar in lib folder of tomcat. However It still does not work